# How to get to secure webpage with using certain certificate, Selenium, Python

Tags: python, firefox, ubuntu, selenium, ssl-certificate

I'm testing secure web application with properly generated certificate. When I opens `https://somesite.com/login` in Firefox browser, dialog window *'User Identification request'* appears and ask to confirm usage of my certificate (that I've already applied). I just press 'OK' and get to login page. But when I try to open it using `selenium` in `Python` code

```
from selenium import webdriver
web_site = 'https://somesite.com/login'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(web_site)
```

I get following error from browser:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to
>
> somesite.com.
>
> SSL peer cannot verify your certificate. (Error code:
>   ssl_error_bad_cert_alert)

with no dialog window and login page... 
Does anyone knows how to avoid certificate usage confirmation with `FirefoxProfile` or maybe in other way?

Comment: have you found solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to replicate the 'OK' click functionality on Selenium ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath of the click button here>")
element.click()
```

Comment: yes, I could, but, as I said, there's no dialog window when I run my script as well as "OK" button...